# How to prevent Typescript class member from changing type?

Tags: typescript

I am using Typescript since few years and I'm still discovering it's magic.

I am wondering why is it possible for a class member to change type on runtime although it has been defined as another in code ?

I have a small example:

```
class TestClass {
    myArray: Array<number>

    constructor(map: any) {
        this.myArray = map.TEST
    }
}

const map1 = { TEST: "[]" }
const test1 = new TestClass(map1)
console.log(typeof test1.myArray)

const map2 = { TEST: [] }
const test2 = new TestClass(map2)
console.log(typeof test2.myArray)
```

Output is then:

```
[LOG]: "string"
[LOG]: "object"
```

I understand that because of the `any` in the constructor param, the compiler is not prenventing bad type or undefined value for `map`.

But I dont get why `typeof` the class member is depending on type of the value we assigned. Why isn't it trying to do a cast to match the declared class member type?

And subsequent question: how to be sure when coding this situation does not happen? Given we do not know exactly the type of the map object's members.

The example in the playground: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEAqCmEAuBhcVoG8BQ0-QFsBPAQQCcywiAuacyogHgDsBXAgI3jID5td8wAPbNkZVsCRCyACgJgADrTDMiASiwD8+JAAsAlhAB0xelWgBeQoqOwAogGVYW6AF9s77MNFJrCgIyWWHCOsLQARADaALrhbl4iyNBIiEiBVszwAO5wqWiQEHKK-moJokIg8EYgQgDmMkhECvBCAGbJqf4mpBRUpWVJ8goATEGYIU60MfHeSSnIoxnZucj5UEUjpbMVVTX1jc1tHQvdZupAA

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

> But I dont get why typeof the class member is depending on type of the value we assigned. Why isn't it trying to do a cast to match the declared class member type?

The `typeof` you're using is [JavaScript's `typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof), not TypeScript's (which only applies in places where the operand is a type, not a value). It tells you the type of the actual value in the property, which is `string` in your first example and `object` in your second (since arrays are objects, and `typeof` is really limited).

When you do `this.myArray = map.TEST`, since the type of `map` is `any`, TypeScript allows it because you've **explicitly** said `map` is `any`, which bypasses nearly all type check checks — TypeScript assumes you know what you're doing. If `map.TEST` isn't assignment-compatible with `this.myArray`, you end up with TypeScript thinking `this.myArray` refers to an array, but the property actually being a string at runtime.

The moral of the story is: Don't use `any` if you can avoid it, and when you can't avoid it, do runtime validations of values before assinging to things that you've given a definite type (like `this.myArray`).

Comment: Ok get it for the typeof thanks. But then I am wondering why it is accepted to do something like `const someVar: Array<number> = "string"` because in the end it is what is done in constructor when map is containing a string and not an array ? 
This is happening in this: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEAqCmEAuBhcVoG8BQ0-QFsBPAQQCcywiAuacyogHgDsBXAgI3jID5td8wAPbNkZVsCRCyACgJgADrTDMiASiwD8+JAAsAlhAB0xelWgBeQoqOwAogGVYW6AF9s77MNFJrCgIyWWHCOsLQARADa-gA0AEwAuuFuXiLI0EiISIFWzPAA7nBZaJAQcor+aqmiQiDwRiBCAOYymcj+JqQUVA3wzE16VdXp8gpxQZghTrTR8Qkp3ultSOO5BUXIJVDlY1WLtfWNLctxnWZEvf2DQA

Comment: @MicCode - I added to the answer a moment ago and think I happened to answer that question. Basically: Because of `any`. Note that `const someVar: Array<number> = "string";` **doesn't** work, because the type of `"string"` is not `any`. But if you add `as any` to it, [it's allowed](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBBIFsCmA1AhgJwFwwIIYzQE8AeMAVwQCMkMA+GAXhgCJoMBLMAcxZjQj8wRANxA).

Comment: Oups sorry I didnt see your edit.
Ok so this is allowed because of the any I understand. Is there any config for typescript that could force coder to not use any / is it a good practice ? 

And if typeof is not enough in typescript, how to ensure good type of value ? instanceof ? (but is it working with primitives?)

Comment: I don't think there's a TypeScript setting preventing *explicit* `any` as in the example. There's `noImplicitAny` which prevents implicit use. You have to write code to check, which of course varies depending on your value. But in this case, just don't use `any` at all.

Comment: Ok, thank you really much for the answers, I'll stick to the "avoid using any" when possible.